# How to import Eclipse syntax highlighting profile in Netbeans for Java projects?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, syntax-highlighting

I have to use both IDEs and I would like to use the Eclipse style of syntax highlighting in Netbeans. Does any one know how to import it (or change any configuration file)? I've already set Netbeans to use the Eclipse key bindings.

Is there any better way than manually changing the colors of every keyword for the Java editor?

Thanks,

Luís

Answer (score 16):

You can change the style of syntax highlighting in NetBeans by going to **Tools > Options** and selecting the **Fonts & Colors** tab.

In order to import a syntax highlighting profile use the **Import** button from the above mentioned Options window.

A ready-to-use Eclipse-like syntax highlighting profile for NetBeans can be found here: https://github.com/Boris-de/eclipsecolors_for_netbeans/downloads.

Comment: Thank you very much. I love eclipse coloring scheme.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what cristiantolnai said, for mac users, go to **NetBeans** -> **Preferences** -> **Fonts & Colors** and the **import** button on the bottom left.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible yet. Both IDEs have different systems to store settings on global or project level. I know that there is a plugin that lets you import Ecplise projects into NetBeans.

Comment: Do you remember the name of that plugin?

Comment: @LuisSoeiro No plugin is necessary to import an Eclipse project into NetBeans.  Just use `File > Import Project > Eclipse Project...`